# Mvc validation and loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

In form post method in MVC view, 
if validation fires then loader should not come and display only validations
else no validations fire then loader should come and save the data.

What I have tried:

placed loader on form submit in javascript and disable the button.

```js
$("#frmContact").submit(function (e) {
        $(".loading").css("display", "inline");
    });
```

1) loader : Issue is that if validation fires, then loader also come alongwith validations and then need to reload the page and input data.

2) Disable Submit button : If I disable the Submit button on click and if validation fire then after button remains the disable instead enable. So if validation is there then enable the button and if validations are not fire then disable the button.

All this to avoid the duplicate entry as if button enables then if user clicks on submit.

Comment: Do you mean that if there are no validation errors then the form should be submitted, and what  if there are errors?

Comment: Yes,  if there are no validation errors then the form should be submitted and loader should display as it is processing, but if there are validations errors, loader should not display and only validations should display.

Comment: Unclear what you expecting. When you submit, you immediately leave the page. What is the point of your `$(".loading").css("display", "inline");` - at best it would display for only a split second

Comment: Hi Stephen, All I am expecting is that if model validations are display then  loader should not come, only display validations messages and if there are no vadalidations then loader should come. the above code is just sample that I am displaying loader like this. When I submit, loader is displaying, l am not immediately leaving the page. after saving record to DB then I am leaving.

Comment: Did you not understand my comment - as soon as you submit you LEAVE the current page  - you 'loader' is pointless

Comment: When I Press submit, loader is displaying untill saving record to DB then I am leaving.

Comment: If you want to check if the form is valid, then use `if ($(this).valid()) { ... }`

Comment: Hi, Stephen. Yes it worked for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check validation on form submit or button submit event using javascript.

```js
 if($('#MyForms').valid())
 {
    // Do something (Valid)
 }
 else
 {
   // Do something (invalid)
 }
```

Comment: Yes that is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

HTML :

```
<div id="ajax-loader" style="display:none;">
     <img src="<?php echo $loaderSrc; ?>" style="height: 200px;width: 200px;">
</div>

<input type="submit" id = "btnSubmit" value="Submit" name="yt0" onclick="return validateForm();">
```

In script : (here you can change the fields...i am showing one of my example)

```
var error_flag = true;
var error_required = true;

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(error_flag && error_required){
            $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "block");
           $('form#login-form').submit();
    }
});

function validateForm(){

var user_pass = document.getElementById('LoginForm[user_pass]').value;
var dob = document.getElementById('LoginForm_dob').value;
var re_pass = document.getElementById('re_pass').value;
var user_name = document.getElementById('LoginForm[user_name]').value;
var email = document.getElementById('LoginForm[email]').value;
var tnc = document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked;
// alert(tnc);
var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

if(user_name == ''){
  validate('LoginForm[user_name]','Nick name is required.');
}else if(email == ''){
  removeerror('LoginForm[user_name]');
  validate('LoginForm[email]','Email is required.');
}else if(!filter.test(email)){
  removeerror('LoginForm[email]');
  validate('LoginForm[email]','Please enter valid email.');
}else if(user_pass == ''){
  // removeerror('LoginForm[email]');
  validate('LoginForm[user_pass]','Password is required.');
}else if(user_pass.length < 6){
  removeerror('LoginForm[user_pass]');
  validate('LoginForm[user_pass]','Min length should be 6.');
}else if(re_pass == ''){
  removeerror('LoginForm[user_pass]');
  validate('re_pass','Repeat password is required.');
}else if(user_pass != re_pass){
  removeerror('re_pass');
  validate('re_pass','Password does not match.');
}else if(dob == ''){
  removeerror('re_pass');
  validate('LoginForm_dob','Dob is required.');
}else{
  if(tnc == false){
    document.getElementById('tnc_check').innerHTML = 'Please agree Terms and Condition' ;
    document.getElementById("tnc_check").style.color = "red";
    error_required = false;
  }else{
    error_required = true;
   document.getElementById("tnc_check").style.display = "none";
   removeerror('LoginForm_dob');
  }
}
}
function validate(id,msg){
     document.getElementById(id).style.border='4px solid red';
     document.getElementById(id).value = "";
     document.getElementById(id).placeholder = msg;
     error_required = false;
}
function removeerror(id){
     document.getElementById(id).style.border='none';
     error_required = true;
}
```

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with asp.net-mvc!

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple. put valid in the form post event. all is what you want.

```js
$("#frm").submit(function (e) {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(".loading").css("display", "inline");
        }
    });
```